# What causes mongoimport to be slow?

Tags: mongodb

On average, mongoimport, which used to finish in 1 hour, takes 6 hours and ends. What is the cause of the sudden slow performance?

```
mongoimport --host 11.11.11 --port 27017 --db naver_report --collection {tbl_name} --file {list} --numInsertionWorkers 8 --jsonArray
```

In this form, we are accessing the internal IP and importing it to another server.

Could it be that there is a problem with the network that is causing the sudden slowness? what could be wrong?

Comment: So many questions ... `--host 11.11.11`? So the host is actually at `11.11.0.11`? ...and mapped to your internal network? `--collection {tbl_name}` ... is this always a new collection, or inserting into an existing collection? `--file {list}` ... Is the file size more or less constant?  `--jsonArray` ... the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--jsonArray) say _"Limited to imports of 16 MB or smaller."_  Is your file that small?  How big is it?  Was the target collection created before executing `mongoimport`?  If so, were any indexes created?

Comment: Thanks for your interest

11.11.11 is the internal network
{tbl_name} is an existing collection. Of course, the index is also set.
The size of the file is not constant Some of the files are large and some are small Some documents exceed 16MB

If it took an hour to import a capacity of about 13 gigabytes, it suddenly took 6 hours, which is embarrassing.

Comment: 13GB data is divided into about 200,000 json files and mongoimport is being executed. Therefore, mongoimport is also connected 200,000 times.

Comment: If the collection is growing in size, then all the indexes will need to be updated with each insert.  If the collection is not in use during `mongoimport`, the indexes could be dropped during all the inserts and then re-created after `mongoimport` is finished.

Comment: Thank you, we will take your opinion into account to solve the problem.